# Django, problem with relations ManyToMany

Tags: django-models

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    title =     models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)
    body_text = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    author =    models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

class User(models.Model):
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    entries = models.ManyToManyField(Entry)
```

So, i have a model **"Entry"** that have a field of type User called "author". The problem is that the **User** model not been created yet, so when i run `syncdb` i get an error.

Can anybody help me to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reference the relationship between the models in both class definitions.  Try this instead:

```
class User(models.Model):
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Entry(models.Model):
    title =     models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)
    body_text = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    author =    models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
```

Comment: And change models.ForeignKey to models.ManyToManyField if each entry can have multiple authors